# What would be a good application for an enhanced version of MapReduce that shares information between Mappers?

Tags: scala, hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce, computer-vision

I am building an enhancement to the Spark framework (http://www.spark-project.org/).  Spark is a project out of UC Berkeley that does MapReduce quickly in RAM.  Spark is built in Scala.

The enhancement I'm building allows some data to be shared between the mappers while they are computing.  This can be useful, for example, if each of the mappers is looking for an optimal solution, and they all want to share the current best solution (to prune out bad solutions early).  The solution may be slightly out of date as it propagates, but this should still speed up the solution.  In general, this is called the branch-and-bound approach.

We can share monotonically increasing numbers, but also we can share arrays, and dictionaries.

We are also looking at machine learning applications where the mappers describe local natural gradient information, and then a new best current optimal solution is shared among all nodes.

What are some other good real-world applications of this kind of enhancement?  What kinds of real, useful applications might benefit from a Map Reduce computation with just a little bit of information-sharing between mappers.  What applications use MapReduce or Hadoop right now but are just a little too slow because of the independence restriction of the Map phase?

The benefit can be to either speed up the map phase, or improve the solution.

Comment: I've used zookeeper for this before.

Comment: There's a recent research paper called "Adaptive MapReduce using Situation-Aware Mappers" ([PDF](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2012-Berlin/papers/edbt/a45-vernica.pdf); [slides](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~rares/pub/edbt12-vernica-slides.pdf)) that describes a system where mappers can communicate with each other through a distributed meta-data store (ZooKeeper).  This is used to implement several adaptive runtime optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

> The enhancement I'm building allows some data to be shared between the mappers while they are computing.

[Apache Giraph](http://incubator.apache.org/giraph/) is based on [Google Pregel](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/large-scale-graph-computing-at-google.html) which is based on [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_Synchronous_Parallel) and is used for graph processing. In BSP, there is data sharing between the processes in the communication phase.

Giraph depends on Hadoop for implementation. In general there is no communication between the mappers in MapReduce, but in Giraph the mappers communicate with each other during the communication phase of BSP.

You might be also interested in [Apache Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) which implements BSP and can be used for more than graph processing.

There might be some reason why mappers don't communicate in the MR. Have you considered these factors in your enhancement?

> What are some other good real-world applications of this kind of enhancement?

Graph processing is one thing I can think of, similar to Giraph. Checkout the different use cases for BSP, some might be applicable for this kind of enhancement. I am also very interested what other have to say on this.

Comment: I recently used BSP for various machine learning tasks, e.G. random forrests and k-means clustering.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - The OP was about usage of communication between mappers. So, if random forests and k-means clustering are implemented on MR, could they could take advantage of communication between mappers? If I am not wrong, anything which has lot of iterations could take advantage of communication between mappers.

Comment: No, you can just save the iterations by replacing it with BSP. Communication within the mappers won't give you the result. However, you could map everything into RAM and do the communication in the map task. This would be a system like giraph then.

Comment: Algorithms which require barriers (all the mappers have to finish first, and then the next iteration starts from that point) will be hard to translate into a system that has mappers communicating the whole time.  For example, K-means requires barriers, and if the mappers try to communicate the means all in the same iteration, then convergence is not guaranteed

Comment: `Algorithms which require barriers (all the mappers have to finish first, and then the next iteration starts from that point) will be hard to translate into a system that has mappers communicating the whole time.` - this is what exactly happens in Giraph. Each map task has multiple super steps and communicates with other map tasks.